# Ajax GET Request is duplicating page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have been reading up on Ajax and am following along on W3Schools.com. I am using Ajax/PHP/MySQL. So far I've gotten the request to successfully query my database based on a button selection, however it's reprinting my entire page when I click on one of the buttons.

Here is the Ajax code:

```
<script>
    function statusShow(status) {
        if(status == "") {
            document.getElementById("exams").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("exams").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "rspamanager.php?st="+status, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is part of the PHP that is printing a table

```
if(isset($_GET["st"])) {
        $st = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["st"]);
    } else {
        // default status
        $st = "open";
    }
        if($connection) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM exams WHERE status = '{$st}'";
            $sth = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
etc ...
```

This is all in the same php file "rspamanager.php".

EDIT: Button code:

```
  <button onclick="statusShow(this.value)" value="open" class="status_open">Open</button>
<button onclick="statusShow(this.value)" value="closed" class="status_closed">Complete</button>
```

Comment: Could you please post the html code which binds the statusShow function to the button click?

Comment: also post more of the php please

Comment: I have added the html button code and some more of the php. The rest of the php is the code to print each result in a table. If more is needed let me know, just didn't want it to get too long.

Comment: If the page is refreshing itself then you have a form on your page and the action on the form is being activated because there is a Javascript error. Open your page. Press th F12 key, open the source tab, set a breakpoint at the start of the showStatus() and single step through your code.You will know when you find the error because the page will automatically refresh itself.

Comment: @jeff I did have a few input fields outside of the div, but I removed it completely and still came across the same problem. The entire html page reprints in the <div id="exams"> area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's help, it was a silly mistake. I ended up putting all of the code to generate the table in a separate file to call and it worked. Not because of the separate file, it just made me understand the request a bit better.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?st="+st, true);
```

My problem was that I had my PHP script that was being called hard-coded into the page, so it was written, and then written again when called. Copy/pasting all the hard-coded PHP script into a separate file fixed this and made it easier to understand.

Julie mentioned that the script was simply giving me a full page instead of just the section I needed which made the solution click with me.

Also, thank you Bryan for the suggestion to use no-cache options.

Answer (score 1):

My test document seems to work just fine, added no-cache options, otherwise seems ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
    function statusShow(status) {
        if(status == "") {
            document.getElementById("exams").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "test.txt", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2005 00:00:00 GMT");
        xhttp.send();

        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="exams">test</div>
 <button onclick="statusShow(this.value)" value="open" class="status_open">Open</button>
<button onclick="statusShow(this.value)" value="closed" class="status_closed">Complete</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "rspamanager.php?st="+status, true);
```

to

```
`xmlhttp.open("GET", "rspamanager.php?st="+status+"&" + Math.random() + '=' + Math.random() * Math.random(), true);`
```

and see if that makes a difference.

If that works, you can leave it like that but should consider adding headers to prevent caching.

Comment: I was still not able to see any parameters appear in the URL, and it didn't fix the duplicate page problem either sadly

Comment: The address bar doesn't change when you run AJAX requests.

Comment: Ah, okay good to know. Everything is working perfectly then except for the page duplicating.

Comment: Are you sure it's not showing the same thing simply because nothing has changed?

Comment: When I click either of my two buttons, the table data changes appropriately with the correct records. The problem is that the whole entire webpage (navigation, header, etc) reprints in the area where the table should be in addition to the records.

Comment: That problem doesn't match your question at all.

Comment: That means that the PHP script you call doesn't output what you want it to output.  It sends you a full page instead of the section you want.  You'll need to change that with an additional parameter or by calling a different script.

Comment: Another possible problem might be that you fetch the output data before doing the DB update, which is quite common for this type of situation.